# glfwSetCursorPos teleporting cursor after setting its location

Tags: c++, glfw

I am using glfw with version 3.3.8 (the one from arch repository) in my c++ code. I call glfwSetCursorPos to set the position of the cursor to a location I chose. And it works, it moves to where it's supposed to be. But when I try to move it slightly, it teleports a little southeast (how much depends on the specified position)

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

constexpr int destinationX = 100, destinationY = 100;

int main () {

    glfwInit ();
    
    GLFWwindow * window = glfwCreateWindow (100, 100, "app", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwSetCursorPos (window, destinationX, destinationY);

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

How do I make it so that it stays in place after? I am using arch linux and tested it both with awesome window manager and with i3 window manager with the same results.